# Make User To Interact With only One Table on Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have DataBase that have more than 200 tables in it.
I need to give user access to only one table.

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Can you please suggest how can I grant access to user to only one table.

Comment: Rephrase question. Remove strange capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `grant`

```
GRANT INSERT ON YourTable TO SomeUser
```

Comment: I Have More Users dbo ,sys ,master 
this will Give validationm such as dbo  
GRANT INSERT ON DetailsTO dbo
 To INsert only to This Table ? ?

Comment: I didnt get what you saying. can you explain. dbo, sys, master are your user names ?

Comment: When Open Database From SQlServer 
We Find Folder Called Security Have Sub folder Called users 
There Are More User (dbo, sys, master)  
I need To Give Validation For This User Such AS 
I Need The User dbo To Interact With One Table 
on the DataBase

Comment: dbo is the schema not the user. roles are user specific.

Comment: oooooooh Sorry I mean  Folder Security That Have Sub Folder Called Logins Users That Use To Enter To SQLSERVER

Comment: create a user and then fire this query to grant access to this user